# Python Selenium login to website via chrome always fails

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

With Chrome Version 83 below code works, after the chrome upgraded to Version 89 it started failing always. And on Failure, password moves to user name location i.e. appended to username like (usernamepassword)

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\xxxxxxxxxx\chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get("https://xxxxx.com/")
    driver.find_element_by_id('unsafe').click()
    username = browser.find_element_by_name('username')
    username.clear()
    username.send_keys("xxxxx")
    time.sleep(10)
    password = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'password')))
    password.clear()
    time.sleep(5)
    password.send_keys("xxxx")
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.find_element_by_tag_name('button').click()
```

Tried adding the implicit wait, WebDriverwait still the same. Not sure what is causing this. please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a short delay and

```
password.click()
```

before

```
password.clear()
password.send_keys("xxxx")
```

Comment: chromedriver.exe version is same as my chrome browser version i.e. Version 89

Comment: I did try adding the implicit wait / WebDriverWait / time.sleep after & before the password.click but no luck :)

But with the same browser open, if i pass the logins and click on login manually it works. Strange. If i pass from automated script it fails

Comment: It's not about implicit wait. try adding simple sleep delay of 300 milliseconds there before accessing the second element

Comment: Need to debug this issue. I can't do it without having the page URL. Sorry

Comment: I tried same code with different URL, that’s works with out any issue. Not sure why that Page is having issue, tried also with different elements. I did print to see if it’s correct element, everything looks ok

Comment: I understand you. I experienced similar issues several time. Need to debug this.